# How to I add command line arguments (parameters) for pinned applications on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, pinning

On Windows 7 i'm no longer able to change the command line arguments for "pinned" taskbar launcher.

How can we workaround this problem in order to be able to start applications with parameters on Windows 7 (from taskbar).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

(When the application is closed) hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click > Properties

Comment: Nice. Doesn't work with all shortcuts but definitly something I did not know.

Comment: He is right, it does work but only if the application is not already started. You should specify this in the answer.

Comment: Awesome trick, it just saved me tons of reload on chrome (unsecure content issue)

Comment: See answer of Juozas Kontvainis to change options when the app is running.

Answer (score 11):

Open jump menu and right click on a shortcut name and click Properties:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Edit the task bar shortcuts directly from:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick
>   Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to create a shortcut to the application that has the necessary arguments and then pin that shortcut to the taskbar.